# Matching rows of same table using visual basic

Tags: database, vb.net, datatable

This is a simple visual basic windows forms application. Database is a local sqlserver database.

Task is to go through a table with 4 columns: ID, dateTime, onOff, param.

The ID is unique to a specific device, dateTime is a timestamp of when an event occurred, onOff will either be a string "on" or "off", and param is an integer, not unique.

For each ID, say the first row is ID 23 and it is "on" and param is 6, I need to find the matching "off" row for that ID of 23 and param of 6 and calculate the difference in dateTime to determine a duration that the ID was on or off.

This needs to happen for all IDs in the table, approximately 10 million rows. There are multiple on/off pairs for each ID, the key is to find the nearest one regarding dateTime.

I have looked at and tried several ways of doing this to no avail, from datatables and datasets, to pushing everything out to a csv and reading it back in blocks at a time. What is the best method to go about this and what would be your steps?

In the following code, once the user chooses a start and end date, the correct data is placed in the datatable. Now I need to perform the task of matching the rows as stated above.

```
Dim sConnectionString As String
    sConnectionString = "Data Source=[servername];Initial Catalog=[tabelname];Integrated Security=True"

    Dim objConn As New SqlConnection(sConnectionString)
    objConn.Open()

    Dim ID As String
    ID = TextBox1.Text

    Dim startDate As Date
    startDate = DateTimePicker1.Value.Date

    Dim endDate As Date
    endDate = DateTimePicker2.Value.Date

    Dim strSql As String = "SELECT ID, dateTime, onOff, param FROM signalRaw WHERE CAST (dateTime as DATE) between '" & startDate & "' AND '" & endDate & "'"

    Dim dasignalRawComma As New SqlDataAdapter(strSql, objConn)

    Dim dtb As New DataTable
    dasignalRawComma.Fill(dtb)
```

Comment: You gave us nowhere near enough info to help you.  What kind of project is this?  ASP .Net Web Forms?  WPF? etc.

Comment: Which database?  Are you using EF or some type of ORM?  Some code would help...your post is very vague.

Comment: try loading your data using OrderBy SignalID ThenBy dateTime

Comment: The query was incorrect. Datatable is populated correctly, now the task of looping through the table and matching rows as specified is most important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it all in SQL and read the results:

```
SELECT  ID, 
        dateTime, 
        onOff, 
        param, 
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 dateTime 
            FROM signalRaw 
            WHERE id = sr.id 
                AND param = sr.param 
                AND onOff = 'OFF'
                AND CAST (dateTime as DATE)>= '1/1/11'
                AND CAST (dateTime as DATE) >= CAST (sr.dateTime as DATE)
            ORDER BY dateTime


        ) OffTime 
FROM signalRaw sr 
WHERE CAST (dateTime as DATE) between '1/1/11' AND '2/1/11' 
    AND onoff = 'ON'
```

By the way... please store dates as dates.  CASTing is painful.

Comment: at 3 minutes it seems to have matched about 600 rows. There are roughly 10 million, so with that in mind I still need a better solution. I appreciate the query and the idea, that definitely works for "off" durations, I also need to calculate "on" durations, which would only add to the amount of time it takes.

Comment: I bet with some changes (like making the dateTime field a real datetime instead of a varchar to remove the casts) and adding some indexes, that query will be the one you use. You're suggesting that you can write code to match data better than SQL Server. Good luck with that.  I'm sorry that your data model is crap and your not using best practices - please don't expect someone to hand you a "secret key to success" here.

Comment: Please consider making these changes to your datamodel: Change the varchar to a smalldate or datetime.  Add an unique index on ID, PARAM, onOff, and Date.  After doing that, I'll give you a query that calculates time between events (from on to off and off to on).  It's really just joining the tables back to themselves.

Comment: Hey I appreciate the help. Unfortuantely, I'm just a student working as an intern somewhere where best practices aren't in place and I can't change the database. I'm aware it's not perfect, so I don't expect a perfect solution. Again, really appreciative.

Comment: Sorry about your luck.  I hope that your next internship is a little better.

Comment: It wouldn't be an internship if it wasn't interesting! Thanks.

Comment: The bad part is, I believe you're learning bad practices in your internship.  Hopefully you'll learn "what not to do"